# Need assistance with sentence analysis

Tags: python

My code takes sentence and finds a given a word in that sentence.

If the word is in the sentence it needs to say that it has found the word and what positions said word is in.

If the word is not in the sentence it should display an error message.

I have this:

```
print("Please insert your sentence without punctuation")
sentence=(input())
variable1='sentence'
print("Which word would you like to find in your sentence?")
word=input()
variable2='word'
if 'word'=='COUNTRY':
    'variable3'==5
    'variable4'==17
if word in sentence:
    print([word], "is in positions", [variable3], "and", [variable4]);
else:
    print("Your word is not in the sentence!")
```

Comment: When do you expect `'word'=='COUNTRY'` to be True? Did you mean `if word=='COUNTRY'`?

Comment: That sounds like a hefty task for such a short period of time..

Comment: this code is completely useless. have you ever run this code? could you tell us which part of this code doesn't work and what way?

Comment: `'variable4'==17` doesn't do what you think it does. It tests that the *string* `variable4` equals the number 17. An assignment is to a plain name and single equal sign, as in `variable4 = 17`.

Answer (score 0):

Python sequences provide the `index` method. It gives you the index of an element, or raises an error if the element is not in the sequence. On strings, it allows you to find substrings.

```
>>> 'hello world'.index('world')
6
>>> 'hello world'.index('word')
ValueError: substring not found
```

Basically, you have to add input for the sentence and the word to search. That's it.

```
print("Insert sentence without punctuation...")
sentence=input()  # get input, store it to name `sentence`
print("Insert word to find...")
word=input()
try:
    idx = sentence.index(word)
except ValueError:  # so it wasn't in the sentence after all...
    print('Word', word, 'not in sentence', repr(sentence))
else:  # if we get here, IndexError was NOT thrown
    print('Word', word, 'first occurs at position', idx)
```

There are some caveats here, for example 'fooworldbar' will match as well. The correct handling of such things depend on what precisely one wants. I'm guessing you actually want *word* positions.

---

If you need positions in the meaning of "the `n`th word", you must transform the sentence to a list of words. `str.split` does that. You can then work with `index` again. Also, if you want *all* positions, you must call index repeatedly.

```
print("Insert sentence without punctuation...")
sentence = input()  # get input, store it to name `sentence`
words = sentence.split()  # split at whitespace, creating a list of words
print("Insert word to find...")
word=input()
positions, idx = [], -1
while idx < len(words):
    try:
        idx = words.index(word, idx+1)
    except ValueError:  # so it wasn't in the rest of the sentence after all...
        break
    else:  # if we get here, IndexError was NOT thrown
        positions.append(idx)  # store the index to list of positions
# if we are here, we have searched through the whole string
if positions:  # positions is not an empty list, so we have found some
    print('Word', word, 'appears at positions', ', '.join(str(pos) for pos in positions))
else:
    print('Word', word, 'is not in the sentence')
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to deal with some misunderstandings in the presented code.

First,

```
print("Please insert your sentence without punctuation")
sentence=(input())
```

is simpler as

```
sentence = input("Please insert your sentence without punctuation")
```

Now I have a variable called `sentence` wihich should not be muddled with the string `'sentence'`

Similarly we can say

```
word = input("Which word would you like to find in your sentence?")
```

gives another variable `word` again not to be muddled with the string `'word'`

Suppose for the sake of argument we have,

```
sentence = "Has this got an elephant in?"
```

and we search for the word `'elephant'`

The posted code attempts to use `in`, but this will happen:

```
>>> "elephant" in sentence
True
>>> "ele" in sentence
True
>>> "giraffe" in sentence
False
>>>
```

Close. But not close enough. It is not looking for a whole word, since we found `'ele'` in `'elephant'`.

If you `split` the sentence into words, as suggested by the other answer, you can then search for whole words *and* find the position. (Look up split; you can choose other characters than the default `' '`).

```
words = sentence.split()
word = 'ele'
words.index(word)
```

If the word isn't there you will get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'ele' is not in list
```

I will leave the error handling to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use re module:

```
import re

sentence = input('Sentence: ')
word =  input('Word: ')

## convert word in regular expression for search method.
regex_word = r'(' + word + ')(?=\s|$)'

## initialize search var.
search = re.search(regex_word, sentence)

if search:
    while search:
        match_pos = search.span()
        sentence = sentence[:match_pos[0]] + sentence[match_pos[1]:]

        print(word + ' is in position ' + str(match_pos[0]))
        search = re.search(regex_word, sentence)
else:
    print(word + ' is not present in this sentence')
```